# Java JDBC exec procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to execute this SQL code:

```
exec ais_disp.p_lk.p_add_client
(v_sis_id     => 1640,
 v_proc_id    => 1,
 v_time_start => to_date('01032013 00:00','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'),
 v_time_end   => to_date('31032013 23:59','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'));
select * from ais_disp.v_lk_1;
commit;
```

And get a ResultList from this query.

I tried to do it like this:

```
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{call ais_disp.p_lk.p_add_client " +
                    "(1640,
                      1,
                      to_date('01032013 00:00','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'),
                      to_date('31032013 23:59','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'))}");
stmt.execute();
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ais_disp.v_lk_1");
System.out.println(rs2);
while (rs2.next()){
   System.out.println(rs2.getString("LRP_STATUS_NAME"));
}
stmt.close();
```

But it returns empty `ResultSet`. What I did wrong?
The database is Oracle database.

UPDATE:

I have added this string to code before `stmt.executeQuery("select * from ais_disp.v_lk_1")`:

```
stmt.execute();
```

But it still returns no rows.
Maybe I need to add somehow select statement in callable statement. So how to do it?

Comment: Your first `to_date()` call specifies an incorrect format mask (missing space before the `hh24`). As the stored procedure does not return a result set, you should use `execute()` rather than `executeQuery()` - actually I would expect your first `executeQuery()` (to run the stored procedure) to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your `CallableStatement` has never been executed, first execute your stored procedure:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()
```

Your code executes selects query instead of stored procedure, and the select statement is returning no rows.